# How to handle with exceptions in odoo 9?

Tags: exception, odoo-9

my requirement is not to sell products of different categories, so I decided to override create method:

```
from openerp import api
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
from openerp.tools.translate import _
from openerp.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError
class sale_order(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "sale.order"
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    product_ids=[]
    product_categ_ids=[]
    if vals.get('name', 'New') == 'New':
        if vals.get('order_line'):
            order_lines_vals=vals['order_line']  
            for l in order_lines_vals:
                for value in l:
                    if isinstance(value, dict):
                        product_ids.append(value['product_id'])
        if product_ids:
            for j in self.env['product.product'].browse(product_ids):
                product_categ_ids.append(j.product_tmpl_id.categ_id.id)
            product_categ_ids=list(set(product_categ_ids))
            if len(product_categ_ids) > 1:
                raise ValidationError(_("It is not possible to add products belonging to many categories(Only one category is allowed)!"))


    result = super(SaleOrder, self).create(vals)
    return result
```

This code does not let create the sale.order record, which is fine, but does not display a popup window error, I need this popup to be displayed.

Has anyonde correctly handled wit excepction in odoo 9(the classical raise osv.except_osv is depecrated)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

reference: https://www.odoo.com/zh_TW/forum/bang-zhu-1/usererror-returns-tuple-instead-of-string-inside-the-try-odoo-9-111394

```
try:
     print 100 / 0
     raise UserError(_('foo'))
except Exception as e:
     raise UserError(_(str(e)))
```